# Flow: Require that polymorphic type has property

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm trying to correctly type a function that uses Flow generic (or polymorphic) types to paginate an array of objects into a graphql/Relay-style "page" object.

Here's a simplified example:

```
type DBNode = {
  uid: string
}

type Student = DBNode & {
  username: string
}

const students = [{
  uid: '123',
  username: 'user-one',
}, {
  uid: '345',
  username: 'user-two',
}]

type Classroom = DBNode & {
  room: number
}

const classrooms = [{
  uid: '234',
  room: 666,
}, {
  uid: '456',
  room: 667,
}]

type Edge<T> = {
  cursor: string,
  node: T
}

const itemToEdge = <T>(item: T): Edge<T> => ({
  cursor: item.uid,
  node: item
})

type Page<T> = {
  pageInfo: {
    count: number,
  },
  edges: Array<Edge<T>>
}        

const assemblePage = <T>(items: Array<T>): Page<T> => ({
  pageInfo: {
    count: items.length,
  },
  edges: items.map(itemToEdge)
})

const studentPage = (): Page<Student> => {
  return assemblePage(students)
}

const classroomPage = (): Page<Classroom> => {
  return assemblePage(classrooms)
}
```

The error I receive is:

```
cursor: item.uid,
                   ^ Cannot get `item.uid` because property `uid` is missing in `T` [1].
References:
34: const itemToEdge = <T>(item: T): Edge<T> => ({
                                 ^ [1]
```

Is there a to ensure that the polymorphic type `T` is always an object that has a `uid` field?

Alternatively, I tried typing `assemblePage` and `itemToEdge` to require that the item(s) are of a `DBNode` type, which results in:

```
38:   node: item            ^ Cannot return object literal because `DBNode` [1] is incompatible with `T` [2] in property `node`.
References:
35: const itemToEdge = <T>(item: DBNode): Edge<T> => ({
                                 ^ [1]
31:   node: T            ^ [2]
```

[Demo](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAIgQgOQPYBNoF4oG8BQUoCuAligFxQDOwATkQHYDmOAvjjqJFAMrAFp3AomeMjRQAZNjyEKEanQCGAWwjkqtRizYBjJHSqVe-YBSFQA2rnzEyUAOQBGAEwBmOwBppBWfOWr73nIAtHoQHizuUtYk5HYuACwArOHWPooqsYHUQcAA7kjhzAC6bBzQAMIANgoUFNRISEpmIqjQklZQ9Y3kdARKAEZyWji6+oLa1bVdSqaYll4x9q7xKZ0NSuQAbNuezJEdNrFJm6vTW5sA7Lsl7ODQAKIoDBAAPAAqAHxmHdoE1BRIahqGj0BiefB0VrkN7DAD0sKgAEFKsA5IpgEQAG4QSogUg4eFQUYGIiopRvJCPZ5md4fAAUpIgG1giFaAEpyFTXp8hF86bhiYJGeTKU8MFBaQyydCOVAubTeVB+dJfv9AeRhQA6GzgqCQtAasksNnSfBmqC3TgABQUzwVmA6YFtEAAknQAGZIcgdfC6AgCHp9QbUXV7aQQMUUciI6jUBQgF7yz4fFjm81sQnI1G+DHY3H4wmCqA1WQDSoQG3UzCS4VRpGx+MvFpoD6yyvcr7oPkCvQGEtM-rl9s0z5Spl1mNxhOfNvO+3d6RO55uz3e01EpD+4CG8ea8uMYAAC1Duojzzrtc1SgUYDHIq5JuYJpGvcEVD4EAEw8wdNndp4H4CJ2XwdNQEC8PIxa1AOQ7OnS77GBQj46K+RKTHU6zfkqf6vFUJbTMBUSdOBfx0FBpaDhWcETPh6xISwQA)

Edit: Here's a working version of the demo, thanks @Aleksey L for the help!

[Working Demo](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAIgQgOQPYBNoF4oG8BQUoCuAligFxQDOwATkQHYDmOAvjjqJFAMrAFp3AomeMjRQAZNjyEKEanQCGAWwjkqtRizYBjJHSqVe-YBSFQA2rnzEyUAOQBGAEwBmOwBppBWfOWr73nIAtHoQHizuUtYk5HYuACwArOHWPooqsYHUQcAA7kjhzAC6bBzQAMIANgoUFNRISEpmIqjQklZQ9Y3kdARKAEZyWji6+oLa1bVdSqaYll4x9q7xKZ0NSuQAbNuezJEdNrFJm6vTW5sA7Lsl7ODQAKIoDBAAPAAqAHxmHdoE1BRIahqGj0BiefB0VrkN7DAD0sKgAEFKsA5IpgEQAG4QSogUg4eFQUYGIiopRvJCPZ5md4fAAUpIgG1giFaAEpyFTXp8hF86bhiYJGeTKU8MFB3uQWmh6cLoRyoFzabyoPzpL9-oDyMKAHQ2cFQSFobVklhs6T4S1QW6cAAKCmeyswHTADogAEk6AAzJDkDr4XQEAQ9PqDagGvbSCBiijkRHUagKEAvJWfD4sK1WtiE5Go3wY7G4-GCqA1WQDSoQe3UzCSlmiCCysmxpEJpO0hXV7lfdB8l1uz0+v0WolIIPAE1Mig6yuMYAACwjBujzxbwunSgUYAZZIpXPNzHNIz0BiofAgAi7ZjpnbdLx454EPa+HWoEF48lLtSZ-UrXbpZ7GBQB46Ce4yTHU6xXpgN7kF2LxVGW0zPlEnTvn8dBfuWv5Vm6dITEh6zASwQA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define constraint to generic type parameter:

```
const itemToEdge = <T: DBNode>(item: T): Edge<T> => ({
  cursor: item.uid,
  node: item
})
const assemblePage = <T: DBNode>(items: Array<T>): Page<T> => ({
  ...
})
```

From [docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/#generic-types-act-as-bounds-):

> Generics allow you to hold onto the more specific type while adding a constraint